# Symfony2: @Assert\MaxLength and input maxlength attribute

Tags: forms, symfony, doctrine

I got a Doctrine entity having one field:

```
/**
 * @PHPCRODM\String()
 * @Assert\MaxLength(255)
 */
protected $title;
```

Is it possible to force a `maxlength` attribute for the input generated from this field, without having to specify it manually?

Comment: I know nothing about PHPCRODM but if when using ORM you can have `@ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)` in your annotation and it would give you the expected result.

Comment: @cheesemacfly thats wrong, since the Form has pretty nothing to do with the Entity itself.
There is no proper way around the asserts

Comment: @Flask I did try it before posting the comment and it works this way with Symfony 2.3. If you leave the type empty or pass null when adding the field to your form builder, it goes down to the entity to find out how to display it (ie: if you have a date field, it displays differently than a string one). the same way if your field in the entity definition can be null, the HTML5 required flag isn't set.

Comment: @cheesemacfly it detects the type of your field. It is the same as you have a browser not understanding HTML5 required, but no nullable true in on your column. It will result in a fatal SQl error.

Comment: @Flask I do agree with you. But the question was about having the `maxlength` attribut on the input generated for the field and as far as I know, the HTML5 validation is built on the fields attribute, not on the assert. But as you mentioned, it doesn't replace the server validation.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, PHPCRODM does not accept such an option. Sad... :(

> [Creation Error] The annotation @PHPCRODM\String declared on   property [...]\Article::$title does not have a property named "length". Available properties: type, translated, name, property, multivalue, assoc, nullable

Should create a PR when I'll get some free time. :)